# TypeError: undefined is not an object after Sorting an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with different objects and they have different date fields that i want to sort regardless of the property name `created_at`, `order_date` or `updated_at`. How can i sort the array by the nearest date to today's date ? The problem is i have `order_date` is inside another object and when i try to sort i'm having this error message

> TypeError: undefined is not an object b.orderInformation.order.order_date`

```js
const array = [
  { type : 'type1', created_at: '2021-07-31' },
  {
    type : 'type2',
    orderInformation: { order: { order_date: '2021-07-13' } }
  },
  {
    type : 'type2',
    orderInformation: { order: { order_date: '2021-07-07' } }
  },
  { type : 'type1', created_at: '2021-08-05' },
  { type : 'type3', updated_at: '2021-09-05' }
];

const res = array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(b.orderInformation.order.order_date ?? b.created_at ?? b.updated_at) - new Date(a.orderInformation.order.order_date ?? a.created_at ?? a.updated_at);
})
```

Comment: orderInformation is undefined in the first element of the array (it doesn't exists)

Comment: @Ariel i know.. i said the array contains different objects

Comment: Yes, that's why you are getting the error. you'll need to check if the object has the property you are expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll need to use the optional chaining operator to allow for gracefully handling properties that don't exist on your objects -

```
a.orderInformation?.order?.order_date
```

and

```
b.orderInformation?.order?.order_date
```

```js
const array = [
  { type : 'type1', created_at: '2021-07-31' },
  {
    type : 'type2',
    orderInformation: { order: { order_date: '2021-07-13' } }
  },
  {
    type : 'type2',
    orderInformation: { order: { order_date: '2021-07-07' } }
  },
  { type : 'type1', created_at: '2021-08-05' },
  { type : 'type3', updated_at: '2021-09-05' }
];

const res = array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(b.orderInformation?.order?.order_date ?? b.created_at ?? b.updated_at) - new Date(a.orderInformation?.order?.order_date ?? a.created_at ?? a.updated_at);
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: But is this really a question and/or answer that will help future readers? _Check the existence before you use it?_

Comment: @Andreas, no need on `created_at` and `updated_at`, they are strings, not objects